# Portable database for a html/javascript project

Tags: javascript, electron

I am working on a project which is currently local and serverless, so I'm not using mamp or similar, I'm just running the pages from the browser.
I would normally use mySQL but as I'm not using php in this project I'd like to know what are the easiest options I have.

I just need a database where I will be storing the page content and then populating the pages from it.

I need something that I'm going to be able to use with Electron too as the project is finally going to be wrapped in Electron.

What options do I have where I can move the project folder around and still be able to use it, in other words, portable ... what options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) Might be what you are looking for - basically, SQLite is, according to the project site, an in-process library that implements a **self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration** (here I read portable as well), transactional SQL database engine.

As an aside, please note the following in terms of your question (requesting recommendations of a tool from the community):  Questions that request the community to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [LokiJS](http://lokijs.org). It's lightweight and has worked for me while using Electron.

Answer (score 0):

Try neDB, it's a non-SQL database if you need that

Answer (score 0):

[Realm](https://realm.io/news/first-object-database-realm-node-js-server/) just announced their DB for the NodeJS platform, I have not tried it yet but looks like something else that you might look into.  Should work with ElectronJS.